How to avoid timeout error in Dapper data access
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 6 project. I am using Dapper for my data access. When I used the data access on a long-running stored procedure, I got a timeout error.
This stored procedure usually takes 11 minutes to complete when run in SSMS. When I tried commandTimeout:900, the query was completed right away but returned no result set. I also tried the QueryAsync() method with the same timeout issue.
public IEnumerable<ProjectDetailsByYear> GetRiskByYearAsync(ReportsConfigurationVM reportsConfigurationVM)
{
    var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    parameters.Add("@ProjectDetailsID", reportsConfigurationVM.ProjectDetailsID, DbType.String);
    parameters.Add("@ProjectNumber", reportsConfigurationVM.ProjectNumber, DbType.String);
    parameters.Add("@ProjectName", reportsConfigurationVM.ProjectName, DbType.String);  

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        var projectDetails = connection.Query<ProjectDetailsByYear> 
                                        ("proc_GetProjectDetailsByYear", 
                                         parameters, 
                                         commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
                                         commandTimeout: null);
         return (IEnumerable<ProjectDetailsByYear>)projectDetails;
    }
}

This is the error I am getting:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (258): The wait operation timed out.
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteReaderWithFlagsFallback(IDbCommand cmd, Boolean wasClosed, CommandBehavior behavior) in //Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1133
at Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryImpl[T](IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition command, Type effectiveType)+MoveNext() in //Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 1161
at System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)   at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable1 commandTimeout, Nullable1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 801   at Project.DataAccess.Dapper.Reports.Reports.GetRiskByYearAsync(ReportsConfigurationVM reportsConfigurationVM) in D:\Projects\Main\ProjectUpdate\ProjectNew\Project.DataAccess\Dapper\Reports\Reports.cs:line 68   at ProjectNew.Controllers.ProjectReportsController.ProcessReport(ReportsConfigurationVM reportsConfigurationVM) in D:\Projects\Main\ProjectUpdate\ProjectNew\ProjectNew\Controllers\ProjectReportsController.cs:line 82   at lambda_method101(Closure , Object)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask1 actionResultValueTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
ClientConnectionId:eaa90f24-e94d-4648-a41c-94463b0cf149
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11


Troubleshoot query time-out errors, is showing a default timeout of 0, not null.(Sorry no time to see if that can make a difference)

For long running tasks, it would be advisable to move them out of the normal flow of execution and make use of either .NET background tasks or a technology like Quartz / Hangfire or Azure Functions / AWS Lambda. This obviously introduces the question of "How do I notify my user that the report is ready?". The answer to that will depend on your use case.

I agree with @Peppermintology. Move it out of the main code. You can use a notification service, maybe using signalR to notify the user about the status of the task.

Option 1 (easy): Increase SqlConnection.CommandTimeout.
Option 2 (better): improve your SQL and/or DB performance (eg. better choices of indexes).
Without access to schema and query plans I can't be more specific.
